# How come primitives can skip "new Object" instantiation in Java?

Tags: java, object, primitive

For example if you have an integer:

```
int i = 9;
```

How can it do that? I mean the full syntax is:

```
int i = new Integer(9);
```

How does it skip the whole new Integer() part and still work?

Thanks.

Comment: you are mixing primitive types and objects.

Comment: primitives are by definition, not objects. You cannot have a reference to a primitive and it cannot exist alone on the heap.

Comment: Those lines are not equivalent.  Specifically, the second line involves an extra gratuitous object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new Integer()` is not a primitive; it's a *boxed* primitive.
Actual primitives (`int`, etc) are not objects and cannot be instantiated.

Note that you can also write  `Integer x = 9`, and the Java compiler will implicitly insert `new Integer()`.
This is called auto-boxing.

Comment: @Eugene (auto-)boxing means wrapping a primitive with the according wrapper object (int -> Integer, double -> Double, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't skip it, because primitives aren't objects.

Your second line of code involves [*auto-unboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), which was a later addition to the Java language.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you wanna have a look into [AutoBoxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

```
Primitive : Reference Mapping
byte : Byte
short : Short
int : Integer
long : Long
float : Float
double : Double
bool : Boolean
char : Character
```

> Autoboxing / unboxing is the automated under the covers conversion
>   between primitive types and their equivalent object types. For
>   example, the conversion between an int primitive and an Integer object
>   or between a boolean primitive and a Boolean object. This was
>   introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score 2):

Primitives and object are two different things. Without primitive you wouldn't be able to  create Integer object like `new Integer(9)` (Integer uses primitive `9` inside constructor).

Answer (score 2):

Your question would have made a lot more sense if it asked why

```
Integer i = 9;
```

works without `new` and then the answer would be "due to auto-boxing of primitives introduced in Java 5". So maybe that's what you really wanted to ask :)